# storing original upload filename (web2py)

Tags: python, web2py

I'm attempting to do something simple and documented well, except for that it's not working on my web app.

essentally i want to save some extra attributes for the uploaded files, like original filename, email of user and also the upload date.

Now following the web2py documentation i've created this submit view. It is almost word for word copied from the documentation section [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Storing-the-original-filename)

I have a controller data.py

```
def submit():

  import datetime

  form = SQLFORM(db.uploads, fields=['up_file'], deletable=True)

  form.vars.up_date = datetime.datetime.now()
  form.vars.username = auth.user.email

  if request.vars.up_file != None:
    form.vars.filename = request.vars.up_file.filename

  if form.process().accepted:
    redirect(URL('data', 'index'))
  elif form.errors:
    response.flash = "form has errors"
```

and my db.py excerpt:

```
db.define_table('uploads',
    Field('username', 'string'),
    Field('filename', represent = lambda x, row: "None" if x == None else x[:45]),
    Field('up_file', 'upload', uploadseparate=True, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_UPLOAD_FILENAME(extension=ext_regex)]),
    Field('up_date', 'datetime'), 
    Field('up_size', 'integer', represent= lambda x, row: quikr_utils.sizeof_fmt(x) ), 
    Field('notes', 'text'))
```

Currently the validation doesn't appear to do anything, when I submit my function, the filename isn't getting saved for some reason, and i get an error elsewhere because the value is None

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this :

**DB :**

```
db.define_table('t_filetable',
Field('f_filename', type='string', label=T('File Name')),
Field('f_filedescription', type='text',
      represent=lambda x, row: MARKMIN(x),
      comment='WIKI (markmin)',
      label=T('Description')),
Field('f_filebinary', type='upload', notnull=True, uploadseparate=True,
      label=T('File Binary')),
auth.signature,
format='%(f_filename)s',
migrate=settings.migrate)
```

**Controller : (default.py)**

```
@auth.requires_login()
def addfile():
    form = SQLFORM(db.t_filetable, upload=URL('download'))
    if form.process(onvalidation=validate_filename).accepted:
        response.flash = 'success'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    return dict(form=form)

def validate_filename(form):
    if form.vars.f_filename == "":
        form.vars.f_filename = request.vars.f_filebinary.filename
```

Function `validate_filename` is called AFTER the form has been validated, so `form.vars` should be available to use here. Function `validate_filename` checks if `form.vars.f_filename` has any value other than `"" (blank)` ; if not, it reads the filename from the `request.vars.f_filebinary` and assigns it to the `form.vars.f_filename` . This way you can allow users to provide an optional field for filename. If they leave it blank, and just upload the file, the `f_filename` in DB will be the original filename.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your pasting your code into web2py to see where it goes wrong and it actually worked for me (at least the file names saved). Maybe the problem is elsewhere?